# Port doesn't recognized while running multiple app of react on windows

Tags: reactjs, npm, environment-variables, create-react-app

I have multiple react apps example one parent app and in the parent app I have two more apps which are running on different port parent app is running on 3000 port and first child is running on 3005 and second child is running on 4000 port. I did some configurations in the package.json file in scripts section given below

parent app has

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "odmit": "npm start odmit_view",
    "moderator": "npm start --prefix moderator",
    "monitor": "npm start --prefix monitor",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run odmit\" \"npm run moderator\" \"npm run monitor\""
 },
```

first child have package.json is

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "PORT=4000 react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
```

Second child have package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "PORT=3005 react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

This will fine when I'm running this on ubuntu with command `npm run dev`. When I run same command in windows then it will give me the bellow error that this port is not recognized.

```
'PORT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 [2] operable program or batch file.
[2] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[2] npm ERR! errno 1
[2] npm ERR! monitor@0.1.0 start: `PORT=4000 react-scripts start`
[2] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[2] npm ERR!
[2] npm ERR! Failed at the monitor@0.1.0 start script.
[2] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[1]
[1] > moderator@0.1.0 start D:\odmit_view\moderator
```

What is the issue in this can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you need to set up the environment variable first:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=4000 && react-scripts start"
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to work on different environments (Windows and Ubuntu) like so:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env PORT=4000 react-scripts start"
}
```

Comment: This I have tried for window works fine but now works for ubuntu will I need to define a port in ubuntu too?

Comment: how we can do it on ubuntu

Comment: For using the same config in unix & windows, refer to the alternative of using `cross-env` package. Second example should work